# How to remove words from one dataframe that are not in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all words from `df2`, which are not in `df1`.

My `df1` looks like this:

```
id    text                                 
1     Hello world how are you people    
2     Hello people I am fine  people   
3     Good Morning people              
4     Good Evening
```

My `df2` looks like this:

```
id    text                                 
1     Hello world how are you all
2     Hello everyone I am fine everyone
3     Good Afternoon people              
4     Good Night
```

Expected output of `df2`:

```
id    text                                 
1     Hello world how are you
2     Hello I am fine
3     Good people              
4     Good
```

Edit: It will be good, If I can also get to print the words that I deleted, and their count (total words I removed)

Comment: split the test and get the intersection ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pease take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to work with `sets`, and take the [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of two given lists with corresponding index having [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the strings. Then we can use `sorted` to sort the result according to `df1.text` and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the items in the list back together:

```
res = [' '.join(sorted(set(s1.split()) & set(s2.split()), key=s1.split().index)) 
                                        for s1, s2 in zip(df1.text, df2.text)]
out = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Text'])
```

---

```
print(out)
             Text
0  Hello world how are you
1          Hello I am fine
2              Good people
3                     Good
```

---

For a more readable solution:

```
res = []
for s1, s2 in zip(df1.text, df2.text):
    set_s2 = s2.split()
    set_int = set(set_s2) & set(s1.split())
    s_int = sorted(set_int, key=set_s2.index)
    res.append(' '.join(s_int))

out = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Text'])
```

Comment: Hey, I did `print(pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Text']))` it is empty. It just shows the index from 0-1000 (i have 1000 rows)

Comment: Well not sure what could be wrong... Its working for me... Give it a try with the regular loop, see if you catch why it isnt working?

Comment: My bad, I made some mistakes in my code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Removed from the rows in df1, df2, both?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for not noticing before. But the output of `out` is not as expected.  Let me explain again

Comment: I just want to remove words from `df2` that are not in `df1`.

Comment: Well this is what it is doing... try the loopy version, did a minor change, but IIUC its doing as youre saying

Comment: If `df1` rows are less than `df2`, then `out` contain output of `df1` otherwise `df2`. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is happening because `zip` iterates till the shortest length. You could find the different in length, and append the remaining rows from `df1`?